# CSS font and 'Display'

Tags: css

For the life of me I cannot find documentation explaining what the word 'Display' does in the following css:

```
h1 {
  font: 3em 'Display'  
}
```

According to this post about the css font property

http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-font-shorthand-property-cheat-sheet/

the size and font family are mandatory or the rule is ignored.

I *thought* it must be a built-in font family or something but look at this bin I created:

http://jsbin.com/yuhaw/1/edit?html,css,output

**HTML**

```
  <h1 class="test1">font: 3em 'Display' </h1>
  <h1 class="test2">font: 3em</h1>
  <h1 class="test3">  font-size: 3em;font-family: 'Display' </h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1.test1 {
  font: 3em 'Display'  
}

h1.test2 {
  font: 3em  
}

h1.test3 {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: 'Display'  
}
```

If it was the case I would expect test1 and test3 to look identical but they don't. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the rule `h1 { font: 3em 'Display' }`, the `'Display'` part specifies the font family name. This makes the rule *syntactically* valid, whereas if it is omitted, the rule is syntactically invalid and gets completely ignored. It does not matter here whether the system actually has a font family named `Display`. It probably does not, and then the browser uses some fallback font(s), normally its default font.

By the definition of the [`font` shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font), this rule sets all font properties to their *initial* values, unless a value is provided for them in the rule. So `font-size` is set to `3em` and `font-family` to `Display` and all other font properties to their initial values as specified in CSS specifications. For `font-weight`, the initial value is `normal`, so the rule overrides the common and recommended browser default that sets `font-weight` to `bold` for `h1`.

As mentioned, the rule `h1 { font: 3em }` is ignored (by CSS specifications and in browser practice), so the element is displayed with default settings (in bold and typically in `2em` size).

The rule `h1.test3 { font-size: 3em; font-family: 'Display' }` is valid and gets applied, but it affects only the two specific font properties that it sets. This means that `font-weight` is `bold`.

Note: Inheritance has nothing to do with this. This is simply a matter of setting properties on an element, in an author’s style sheet and in a browser’s default style sheet. And the key issue here is the effect of the `font` shorthand property.

Comment: The h1.test3 is inheriting from the browser and h1.test1 is inheriting from css default isn't it?

Comment: @MikeCheel, no, CSS inheritance is nothing like that. In it, an element inherits a property from its *parent*, under certain conditions. And, for example, `font-weight` is never inherited except due to an explicit `font-weight: inherit` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why they are not the same is because for Test3 you inherit all the properties that you do not explicitly set. Every existing style is kept, and you only change the size and the family.

Therefore, Test3 is bold, which is the browser default style for H1.

Test1 is a complete font declaration and resets every unspecified property to a default font. That's why Test1 has a font-weight of `normal`. You overwrite every font property by specifying a 'complete' font declaration, so the size and family are set to the specified value and the weight is reset to `normal`, which is browser-default for a font.

In your browser (at least in Chrome), you can inspect the `Computed style`. In that view, you can also check `View inherited properties`. If you do that in your fiddle, you can compare all the font properties, and you'll notice those differences.

Comment: I'm still confused. It seems that the defaults are filled in anyways. What am I missing? Also, any info about the actual 'Display' font family?

Comment: OK after thinking this through some more tell me if this is correct. When using the font rule, the defaults for the rule are used if they are omitted. When specifying specific properties as in Test3 the browser defaults are taken (instead of the rule defaults). Is that right?

Comment: That is right. When specifying specific properties as in Test3, the browser defaults (or any applied CSS) for the other properties are left *untouched*.

Comment: As far as 'Display' it appears to be a browser default. I tried it in Safari on a mac and if you put empty single quotes it is the same as typing 'Display'. Safari and Chrome seem to agree on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it. E.g. Google Chrome helps you to see the computed styles using that notation.

```
element.style {
   font: 3em 'Display';
   font-family: Display;
   font-size: 3em;
   font-style: normal;
   font-variant: normal;
   font-weight: normal;
   line-height: normal;
}
```

As per [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp), you can specify all the font properties in one declaration, using the following notation :

`font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height|caption|icon|menu|message-box|small-caption|status-bar|initial|inherit;`.

Answer (score -1):

there is no such Font Named "Display"

you have to upload the otf to your webserver and enable it that way:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Display";
  src: url("type/filename.eot");
  src: local("☺"),
    url("type/filename.woff") format("woff"),
    url("type/filename.otf") format("opentype"),
    url("type/filename.svg#filename") format("svg");
  }
```

Comment: i ment that there is no such font on a common system. i think he wants to use this font: http://www.dafont.com/display-otf.font